# ¿Como recorrer un arrar json y hacer comparaciones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo un arreglo json de este tipo.

```
[{"Metrica":"Mensual", "Nombre":"Juan", "Puesto":"Operador", "Edad":23},{"Metrica":"Quincenal", "Nombre":"Paco", "Puesto":"Constructor", "Edad":40},]
```

Bien ahora quiero recorrerlo y hacer comparaciones de acuerdo a la métrica.

Aquí esta mi código pero hay un problema y es que cuando solo tengo una métrica no me hace lo que requiero.

```js
  // El arreglo de arriba lo recibo en la varibale col_detalle_subgrid

                    for (var i in col_detalle_subgrid) {
                        for (var j in col_detalle_subgrid[i]) {

                      // Aqui realizo mis comparaciones
                            if (col_detalle_subgrid[i][j] == "Mensual" || col_detalle_subgrid[i][j] == "Quincenal")
                             {
                            
                      // Aquí muestro mis tabs si las condiciones se cumplen 
                                $("#Trabajadores_Nuevos").css("display", "inline-block");
                                $("#Trabajadores_Frecuentes").css("display", "inline-block");
                             
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                               // En caso de que no se cumplan las oculta
                                $("#Trabajadores_Nuevos").css("display", "none");
                                $("#Trabajadores_Frecuentes").css("display", "none");
                              
                            }                               
                        }
                    }
```

El problema es que si el arreglo solo trae un objeto este muestre las dos Tabs y solo debería de mostrar una. Por ahora en la fila de mi subgrid solo muestra esos dos objetos pero en otras filas muestra mas objetos. En total son 5 objetos podria decir que el total de métricas son 5.

Comment: O sea que la metrica `Mensual` pertenece al tab `Trabajadores_Nuevos` y la metrica `Quincenal` a `Trabajadores_Frecuentes`?

Comment: Hola @alanfcm exactamente cada Tab(que contiene controles). pertenece a una metrica de mi arreglo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas dos `for` anidados.  Puedes recorrer el arreglo con `forEach`.  Puedes iniciar con los tabs escondidos y mostrarlos si existen coincidencias en el array.  Algo asi:

```js
// El arreglo de arriba lo recibo en la varibale col_detalle_subgrid
var col_detalle_subgrid = [{"Metrica":"Quincenal", "Nombre":"Paco", "Puesto":"Constructor", "Edad":40}];

                    col_detalle_subgrid.forEach(function(val) {
                      

                      // Aqui realizo mis comparaciones
                            if (val.Metrica == "Mensual") 
                             {
                            
                      // Aquí muestro mis tabs si las condiciones se cumplen 
                                $("#Trabajadores_Nuevos").css("display", "inline-block");
                             }
                             if (val.Metrica == "Quincenal") {
                                $("#Trabajadores_Frecuentes").css("display", "inline-block");
                             
                            }
                                                        
                        
                    });
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Trabajadores_Nuevos">
  Nuevos
</div>
<div id="Trabajadores_Frecuentes">
  Frecuentes
</div>
```